# TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, framer-motion

I am getting an error that doesn't prevent my web application from running but after sometime it just abruptly pops up on the screen. I am using a framer-motion `motion.span` component.

The error is due to this bit of code.

```
const animationProjectsCount = () => {
        animate(0, 30, {
            duration: 1,
            onUpdate: (v) => (projectCount.current.textContent = v.toFixed())
        })
}
```

The entire component code:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { animate, motion } from "framer-motion";
import Timeline from './Timeline';
const Home = () => {
    const projectCount = useRef(null);

    // var element = projectCount.current;

    const animationProjectsCount = () => {
        animate(0, 30, {
            duration: 1,
            onUpdate: (v) => (projectCount.current.textContent = v.toFixed())
        })
    }

    return (
        <div id='about'>
            <div className="abtSections">
                <div className="abtLeft">
                <h1 className='abtHeader'>About</h1>
                    <p>As I strive to achieve my goal of becoming a full-stack developer, I have acquired valuable experience through the completion of various projects at a beginner level, and my accumalated years of programming and project work. Moreover, I possess a notable self aptitude for self-directed learning and am able to apply myself for acquiring new skills at a constrained time frame.</p>
                </div>
                <div className="abtRight">
                    <Timeline />
                </div>
                <div style={{ clear: "both" }}></div>
            </div>
            <div className='projectsDone'>
                <p className='number'>
                    +<motion.span ref={projectCount} whileInView={animationProjectsCount}></motion.span>
                </p>
                <span className='done'>Projects Done</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurring because your `projectCount.current` is null. Make sure your `modion.span` component uses `forwardRef`

For more info checkout - https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html